# Trigger.io: Calling location.reload() we can't access any forge properties

Tags: javascript, reload, trigger.io

We have an html5 Mobile App.

We have a logout function for which we call `location.reload()` so that we can clear all the appended elements in our index.html.

And here comes the problem. We can't now call any forge properties,

a Sample listener is here:

```
    forge.event.connectionStateChange.addListener(function() {
        connectedToInternet = forge.is.connection.connected();
    }, function(error) {
        showAlert(error);
    });
```

It is working for its first time run, and then we click the logout button for which is will reload our index.html file, then `forge.is.connection.connected()` is now undefined.

I hope someone from trigger.io can clear this issue and how can  we prevent this situation.

Any suggestions are all welcome and will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Trigger's code, I've add this to our internal tracker so it gets fixed in the future.

In the mean time, the value of the connection state does seem to be updated if it changes, it just remains as undefined if the page is reload and there is no change. So it should be safe to assume if it is undefined it is the same as it was previously.

That means the following code should make sure `connectedToInternet` always contains the right connection info.

```
var connectedToInternet = false;
forge.prefs.get("connectedToInternet", function (connected) {
    if (connected !== null) {
        connectedToInternet = connected;
    }
});
forge.event.connectionStateChange.addListener(function() {
    var connected = forge.is.connection.connected();
    if (connected != undefined) {
        connectedToInternet = connected;
        forge.prefs.set("connectedToInternet", connectedToInternet);
    }
}, function(error) {
    showAlert(error);
});
```

Comment: Hello, it seems does not solve the case. The code just adding the default value, but it would not call anymore the listener once reloaded. We can't determine the current connection state of the application

Comment: The listener seems to still be called for me after reloading, my test page is http://pastie.org/8163630 I see the log output change if my connection state changes, even after pressing reload.